# ODBC connection Fail VB6

Tags: database, vb6, odbc, driver, vb6-migration

I am working on a legacy VB6 application and I am running into problems with database connection.

I recieve these two errors in respective order:
[image]
and
[image]

and the break happens on this line:

[image]

I made sure that I tried the connection in the ODBC 64bit tool and the 32bit tool. same results

Any suggestions of what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the 32 bit version of ODBC. You can't mix 32 and 64 bit code in the same process.

Use the 32-bit odbc manager to configure your ODBC source:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe